# Unable to construct React.useState on a .json within a Typescript type in a Material UI Dialog

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, typescript, material-ui

I am looking to create a dialog modal that can edit the permissions of a given organization, but I think I'm missing a key point of logic or something else. I'm using Material UI Checkbox to toggle permissions as a Boolean on and off.
My types are defined as follows:

```
export type Organization = {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    added: Date,
    admin: String,
    permissions: AdminPermissions
}

export type AdminPermissions = {
    permission_a: Boolean,
    permission_b: Boolean,
    permission_c: Boolean
}
```

And here is how the dialog modal is set up at the moment

```
interface EditOrganizationDialogProps {
    open: boolean,
    closeHandler: () => void,
    organization: Organization,
}

export default function EditOrganizationDialog(props: EditOrganizationDialogProps) {
    const permissionsList = props.organization.permissions;

    const { open, closeHandler, organization } = props;

    const [permissions, setPermissions] = React.useState([]);


    const permissionChangeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        
        setPermissions(event.currentTarget);

    };


    return (
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={closeHandler}>

            <DialogTitle>
                {'Edit organization permissions'}
            </DialogTitle>

            <DialogContent dividers>
                <FormGroup>
                    {permissionsList.map(()=> (
                    <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox/>}
                        onChange={permissionChangeHandler}
                        value={permissions}label="Permission A">
                    </FormControlLabel>
                    ))}
                </FormGroup>
            </DialogContent>

            <DialogActions>
                <Button
                onClick={closeHandler}
                type='submit'>
                    {'Save'}
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={closeHandler}>
                    {'Cancel'}
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>

        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

The `map` and `useState` I know are wrong, but even the change handler isn't liking the typing. I tend to overdevelop my code when something isn't working, so what steps might I be forgetting that would resolve this?

I have tried the `useState` as both a json object and an array, with differing errors. I want to be able to map the permissions so that when they change in the future, I won't have to adjust this modal. I have seen other questions similar to this, but none involving Checkbox(Boolean) logic.